# Why is this vectorized code subject to vector size?

Tags: c++, vectorization

I compile the following code without vectorization *(-O2)* and compare the time with vectorization *(-O3 -march=native)* for three different vector lengths *(determined by uncommenting the respective `#define SIZE`)*, obtaining 29::9, 247::145 and **4866::4884**, for vector sizes 10000, 100000 and **1000000**, respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include<chrono>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

//#define SIZE (10000) // 29::9
//#define SIZE (100000) // 247::145
#define SIZE (1000000) // 4866::4884


void vector_op_2(int * __restrict__ v1, int * __restrict__ v2) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        v1[i] = 2 * v2[i];
}

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    int* v = new int[SIZE];
    int* w = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        v[i] = i;
    }

    auto start = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());


    for (int k = 0; k < 5000; k++) { 

        vector_op_2(w, v);

    }

    auto end = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    std::cout << "Time " << end.count() - start.count() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (abs(w[i]-2*v[i])>0.01) {
            throw 1;
        }
    }


    delete v;
    return 0;
}
```

1. Why does no speedup occur in the case of vector size 1000000?
2. What is the optimal length?
3. Why does this vector length issue not occur with the following example?

[shortened]

```
long vector_op_1(int v[SIZE]) throw()
{
    long s = 0;
    for (unsigned i=0; i<SIZE; i++) s += v[i];
    return s;
}
```

[... I am using g++ 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 ...]

[... For short vector size 1000 I am achieving a 6:1 ratio! ...]

Comment: The code is just not keeping the processor very busy.  So for large arrays the speed of the RAM becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: -O2 and -O3 are not necessarily just for compare vectorization. use -O3 and -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize -fno-tree-slp-vectorize to compare them. -S shows you the assembly codes